# VSCode Javafile isnt executable

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Whenever I run the following code in VSCode it says its not executable but wont tell me why it isn't. I have tried changing the class name but it says that it also is not executable so im suspecting its something in my code but im not quite sure what

```
public class Car {
    private int yearModel;
    private String make;
    private int speed;

    public Car(int model, String type){
        yearModel = model;
        make = type;
        speed = 0;
    }

    public void setModel(int model){
        yearModel = model;
    }

    public void setMake(String type){
        make = type;
    }

    public void setSpeed(int spd){
        speed = spd;
    }

    public int getModel(){
        return yearModel;
    }

    public String getMake(){
        return make;
    }

    public int getSpeed(){
        return speed;
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MyCar {
    public static void main(){
        getMode();
    }

    public static void getMode(){

        Car model = new Car(1992, "Ford");


        System.out.println(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: what class are you trying to run? what is the name of the file it's in? why do you import JOptionPane? Are both classes in the same package? Are they both compiled?

Comment: In order for a Java class to be "executable", it **must** contain the following method: `public static void main(String[] args)`. Pardon me, but I don't see such a method in the code in your question. I see this method (in class `MyCar`): `public static void main()` Can you see what's missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are making the object in a method that is not being called (you incorrectly called, by setting it up wrong), therefore there is no purpose to it, if you make a main method like this:

Use this:

```
public class MyCar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      getMode();
    }
    //use above
    public static void getMode(){

        Car model = new Car(1992, "Ford");


        System.out.println(model.getModel());
        System.out.println(model.getMake());
    }
}
```

Keep the Car class the same:

```
 public class Car {
    private int yearModel;
    private String make;
    private int speed;

    public Car(int model, String type){
        yearModel = model;
        make = type;
        speed = 0;
    }

    public void setModel(int model){
        yearModel = model;
    }

    public void setMake(String type){
        make = type;
    }

    public void setSpeed(int spd){
        speed = spd;
    }

    public int getModel(){
        return yearModel;
    }

    public String getMake(){
        return make;
    }

    public int getSpeed(){
        return speed;
    } 
}
```

It should now work.

Comment: thank you very much I was doing this while extremely fatigued and didnt even notice I didnt write my main method the correct way thank you!